# Need to find the relative frequencies

Tags: python

Cannot find out why this is not working?:

```
def frequencies(counts):    
    total = sum(counts)
    frequencies = []    
    for count in counts:
        frequencies.append(float(count/total))    
    return frequencies
```

It should take a list of intergers as argument and return a list of relative frequencies.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `sum()` returns an integer and hence you are doing integer division.
Use

```
total = float(sum(counts))
```

instead or

```
frequencies.append(count/float(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand the task, the code should count the frequencies of the numbers met in the list.
I'd suggest this solution:

```
def frequencies(counts):
    stat = {}
    total = float(len(counts))
    for count in counts:
        if count in stat:
            stat[count] = stat[count] + 1
        else:
            stat[count] = 1
    frequencies = []
    for s in counts:
        frequencies.append(float(stat[s]/total))
    return frequencies

frequencies([1,2,1])
[0.6666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.6666666666666666]
```